# Inherited Javascript Object loses property values

Tags: javascript, factory-pattern, abstraction, prototypal-inheritance

I have attempted to create a javascript factory pattern example that utilises a common abstraction using prototypal-inheritance but the values in the console log are coming back undefined.

```
var AthleteFactory = function() {
    var athlete, that = this;

    this.createAthlete = function(athleteType, athleteName, athleteCountry, athleteUnit) {
        switch (athleteType) {
            case "Swimmer":
                athlete = new Swimmer(athleteName, athleteCountry, athleteUnit);
                break;
            case "Runner":
                athlete = new Runner(athleteName, athleteCountry, athleteUnit);
                break;
        }

        return athlete;
    }
};
```

Below is constructor:

```
function Athlete(theName, theCountry, theUnit) {
    this.name = theName;
    this.country = theCountry;
    this.distance = 0;
    this.unit = theUnit;
};
```

Athlete Object (abstract/base object)

```
Athlete.prototype = {
    constructor: Athlete,
    recordDistance: function(distance) {
        this.distance += distance;
    },
    showProgress: function() {
        $("#output").append("<h1>" + this.name + " of " + this.country + " has achieved: " + this.distance + this.unit + "</h1>");
    },
};
```

Extend the Athlete base object

```
var Swimmer = function(theName, theCountry, theUnit) {};
Swimmer.prototype = new Athlete();
Swimmer.prototype.DoExercise = function(difficulty) {
    switch (difficulty) {
        case "easy":
            this.recordDistance(20);
            break;
        case "moderate":
            this.recordDistance(50);
            break;
        case "hard":
            this.recordDistance(100);
            break;
    };
};
```

The DoExercise contains logical differences hence the factory pattern

```
var Runner = function(theName, theCountry, theUnit) {};
Runner.prototype = new Athlete();
Runner.prototype.DoExercise = function(difficulty) {
    switch (difficulty) {
        case "easy":
            this.recordDistance(5);
            break;
        case "moderate":
            this.recordDistance(20);
            break;
        case "hard":
            this.recordDistance(60);
            break;
    };
};
//create some athletes in our factory
var factory = new AthleteFactory();

var phelps = factory.createAthlete("Swimmer", "Micheal Phelps", "USA", "Metres");
console.log(phelps);

var farah = factory.createAthlete("Runner", "Mo Farah", "UK", "Kilometres");
console.log(farah);

phelps.DoExercise("easy");
phelps.DoExercise("moderate");
phelps.DoExercise("hard");
phelps.showProgress(); //undefined of undefined has achieved: 170undefined

farah.DoExercise("moderate");
farah.DoExercise("easy");
farah.DoExercise("hard");
farah.showProgress(); //undefined of undefined has achieved: 85undefined
```

I'm from a C# background rather than Javascript so I'm potentially misunderstanding a fundamental difference or two.  Although I could just create separate functions to achieve the same task it would be nice to get this working,

Here's the codepen link:
http://codepen.io/paulcthomas/pen/aNLJyq?editors=1010

Comment: Are you relying on your C# knowledge to understand how JS works?

Comment: This example is way, way overcomplicated for someone just getting started in Javascript objects and sub-classing.  Start with some working examples from an existing tutorial and then extend them and test to see how it all should work.  Among other things, you should be using `Object.create()` to initialize your prototypes and something like `that = this` inside a factory function makes no sense.  Seriously, start over by following a Javascript tutorial and forget most everything you thought you knew from C++, it will get in your way.

Comment: Perhaps this is just my point, but because C# and javascript are **slightly** (stop laughing) different you should rather start from some easier examples first. There are tons of ways to create a "factory" pattern, but you should first check some javascript tutorials (mostly about anonymous functions, **self invoking anonymous functions**, asyncronous callbacks, callbacks in generals). Again, not that you cannot accomplish that yet, but your example is so complicated for a javascript beginner that there are many points that needs to be addressed first.

Answer (score 0):

In your Swimmer and Runner constructors, you'll have to call the base class' constructor like so:

```
var Swimmer = function(theName, theCountry, theUnit) { 
    Athlete.call(this, theName, theCountry, theUnit);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What you actually want is to inherit a constructor in your sub-class. This doesn't happen automatically in JS. You have to manually call the parent-class constructor in your sub-class constrcutor.

As you can see in [this article](http://javascript.info/tutorial/all-one-constructor-pattern) that is using your same pattern, the general solution is this.

```
var Swimmer = function(theName, theCountry, theUnit) { 
    Athlete.apply(this, arguments)
};
```

At this point if not for easier reading you could also not define the arguments in your sub-class constructor

```
var Runner = function() {
    Athlete.apply(this, arguments)
};
```

> The superclass constructor is called automatically when inhereting.
>   There is no non-ugly way to first inherit, then do something, and then
>   call the superclass constructor.

Comment: Example updated now working with superfluous that = this removed.  I hadn't realised about parent constructor inheritance and the "apply" method.